# Winform showing Excel with series names

Tags: c#, excel

I have winform written by C# showing an excel line graph. I have the basic work but a minor problem with the series name.

My graph should have 4 series (i.e. 4 lines) with N records, that means the excel is 4 x N table. Of course I have some extra blocks with the axis names end up with 5 x (N+1)

Here is the code: (where `count` is the number of records)

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range chartRange;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 400, 350);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;


        if (count == 0)
        {
            chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "E2");    
        }
        else
        {
            chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "E" + (count + 1));
        }
        chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);

        //X-Axis
        if (count == 0)
        {
            chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A2", "A2");    
        }
        else
        {
            chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A2", "A" + (count + 1));
        }
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Axis xAxis = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Axis)chartPage.Axes(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
        xAxis.CategoryNames = chartRange;

        chartPage.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.SeriesCollection seriesCollection = chartPage.SeriesCollection();

        Console.WriteLine("count "+seriesCollection.Count);
        //Series name
        if (count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Series series1 = chartPage.SeriesCollection(i);
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 1:
                        series1.Name = "Line1";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        series1.Name = "Line2";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        series1.Name = "Line3";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        series1.Name = "Line4";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

The graph has no problem with when N >= 4 (that means more than 4 records from database) but shows error when N < 4 because `seriesCollection.Count` < 4. I think the `seriesCollection.Count` should be 4 always, not depends on the number of records. But I don't know what's wrong with the code. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns);
```

It works then...